# Which fits better "more important" or "more importantly"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, adverbs

Sorry - I always think the question is obvious when plainly it is not.

Should I use "important" or "importantly" in the introductory phase of this sentence:

"Appellant's argument is premature.

> *More important,* the argument lacks merit.

or

> *More importantly*, the argument lacks merit.